# problem in installing NLTK in python

Tags: python

i'm trying to integrate NLTK with python although i have installed python 3.7.0 version but it giving this error. what is this error? how it will resolved?[image: error while installing NLTK]

Comment: Welcome. Your question is totally off-topic here, as it is not asking us to recommend any software. I was just about to give you the answer as a comment, but Josem beat me to it (please award him the answer). I am glad that you got help, but this is wrong place to ask that question. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the path where python is installed, to the %PATH% variable of your system.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows) is the way if you don't know.